# Inverting Binary Tree with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, binary-tree, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm pretty comfortable with dealing with inverting a binary tree, with using raw pointers, but I'm struggling when trying to do it with unique_ptrs.

I have a TreeNode class defined as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct TreeNode {
    T val;
    unique_ptr<TreeNode<T>> left, right;
};
```

I currently have this function to invert a binary tree:

```
TreeNode<int>* InvertTree(const unique_ptr<TreeNode<int>>& root) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    auto left = InvertTree(root->left);
    auto right = InvertTree(root->right);
    root->left = make_unique<TreeNode<int>>(right);
    root->right = make_unique<TreeNode<int>>(left);

    return root.get();
}
```

Is this how it should be done? What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: `make_unique` constructs a new object. It's not a "cast" to `unique_ptr`.

Comment: What is `root`? Presumably a `unique_ptr<TreeNode<T>>` but it's not shown. Please be sure to share a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually need is to `swap` pointers. The `unique_ptr` doesn't allow copying, but that is not required in your case: each inversion can be made inplace. Try this to swap two subtrees:

```
std::swap(root->left, root->right);
```

If you need to make an inversed copy, try something like that:

```
unique_ptr<TreeNode<int>> InvertTree(const unique_ptr<const TreeNode<int>>& node) {
    unique_ptr<TreeNode<int>> inverted_node;
    if (node != nullptr) {
        inverted_node.left = InvertTree(node->right);
        inverted_node.right = InvertTree(node->left);
    }
    return inverted_node;
}
```

Some comments regarding your code.

1. Don't return raw pointers if you started working with smart pointers internally.
2. Consider implementing the constructor of your `struct TreeNode`.

Comment: If I want to return a unique_ptr, do I do `return std::move(node)` after modifying the tree in-place using `std::swap(root->left, root->right)` ? I'm getting a compiler error indicating that the copy constructor is trying to be called.

Comment: @Kris It doesn't make any harm if you explicitly show your intention to move an object with the `std::move` function. In my example the RVO optimization should work: compiler can easily detect that the object doesn't need to be copied. In case you don't have the elegance that allows compiler to do the optimization, just use `std::move` explicitly

Comment: I think adding std::move where RVO is expected is generally considered code smell.